# Wiping "swap" partition

Tags: 11.10, installation, swap

I am trying to install Ubuntu 11.10. I partitioned between Windows and Ubuntu, with some free space left. I did not designate a "swap partition." When I start installation, it gets stuck on this message: "Wiping swap space for security." Since I do not have a swap space, this is not applicable. I have tried restarting the installation, to no avail. Help?

Comment: are you saying you can't do a clean reinstall of ubuntu 11.10 or that you have installed it and now you want to create a swap partition for you ubuntu 11.10?

Answer (score 2):

My guess would be that you need to either add a swap partition, or kill off the incomplete install, so it can start again. You shouldn't have got that far, and maybe ought to file a bug on the installer - it should insist on a `swap` partition (it can be small).

Boot from a live CD, and use the `Disk Utility` to re-partition your free space so there is something which can be used as swap. You will probably then need to add this to `/etc/fstab` on the main boot partition.

You need a line something like this:

`/dev/sdb5 none            swap    sw           0    0`

This is fairly involved, and might not be quite as I've described, but it might be enough to get you going. Make sure you do not damage your Windows partition, or the boot sector of the drive. You might need to mount the Ubuntu partition first before you can edit fstab, and it might appear at `media/drive_name/etc/fstab` from the live CD.

Comment: Thanks! That should work but I haven't tried it yet. I'll just make some small amount of swap space.